# get part of the filename in the file content

Tags: xstring, currfile

I would like to print only the characters between `Ch` and `-` in the filename, so I use the packages `currfile` and `xstring`. As example :

```
\StrBetween[1,1]{\currfilename}{Ch}{-}
```

should gives 2 or 14 if the filename is "Ch2-2nde.tex" or "Ch14-2nde.tex", but it does not work.
But still if I try `\StrBetween[1,1]{Ch2-2nde.tex}{Ch}{-}` or `\StrBetween[1,1]{Ch14-2nde.tex}{Ch}{-}` it works fine ! I don't understand ...

Comment: `\currfilename` returns characters with category code 12, that don't match `Ch` of category code 11. The solution by @SunilkumarKS works because the `*` variant applies `\detokenize` (after full expansion) and so `Ch` is transformed in category code 12 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `starred` option of `\StrBetween` command to obtain the result.  This may be used when the input contains commands.  The following example will help:

```
\StrBetween*[1,1]{\currfilename}{Ch}{-}
```

Comment: The purpose of `*` is different, see top of page 15 in the manual. This works, but for a different reason.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `\currfilename` returns a “stringified” file name; in TeXnical terms, all characters have category code 12. However, the characters `Ch` you are supplying in the second optional argument have category code 11, so there's no match.

One possibility is to use the `*`-variant of `\StrBetween`, that applies `\detokenize` to all mandatory arguments (after full expansion), so also `Ch` become category code 12 and the match is found.

Another possibility is to use `l3regex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{currfile,xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\extractnumber}{o}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {
    \mathxlv_extract_number:N \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
   }
   {
    \mathxlv_extract_number:N #1
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mathxlv_extract_number:N
 {
  \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \currfilename
  \regex_replace_once:nnN { \A Ch ([^-]*) .* \Z } { \1 } #1
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\extractnumber

\extractnumber[\thisfilenumber]

\texttt{\meaning\thisfilenumber}

\end{document}
```

If the document is named `Ch2-2nde.tex`, the output is

[image]

If the document is named `Ch14-abc-def.tex`, the output is

[image]